# C# WPF dtatagrid linq sync

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, binding

i have a dtatatable and a linq table and i want to sync this two elements in the way that if i modify something on the talbe the modification is written on the table object and on the sqlbd ( i have generated the dtatbase dml with the visual studio tool.

```
public partial class Admin : Window
    {
        private DatabaseDataContext db;
        private Utente user;
        private Table<Prodotto> prodotti;
        private Table<Ordine> ordini;
        private Table<Utente> utenti;
        private List<Prodotto> insordini;      
public Admin(DatabaseDataContext db1, Utente user1)
            {
                db = db1;
                user = user1;
                prodotti = db.GetTable<Prodotto>();
                ordini = db.GetTable<Ordine>();
                utenti = db.GetTable<Utente>();
                InitializeComponent();
                .
                .
                .
                .
             }
<Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.DataContext>
                    <local:Utente/>
                </Grid.DataContext>
                <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid3" Margin="10,10,16,10" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFA6A6A6">
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
```

at the monemt i use to add after the initcomponent() `dataGrid3.ItemsSource = utenti;`  but if the db is updated the datagrid doesent update automaticaly and if i change the table this does not update the db.